# Quarkus <=3.3.0 Breaks Docker Container - What to do?

Tags: quarkus

I am currently trying to update a project from 3.2.6.Final to the Current Quarkus versions. I am working offile, so the GradleTask does not work for me.
When I update Quarkus, my Tests fail because somehow, Mockito Annotations don't work anymore. I already tried replacing the deprecated @InjectMock with the new one, with no succes.

In addition, I can't use the Gradle-Task "quarkusUpdate" because I am offline for security reasons (coperate guidelines)
How can I get Quarkus to work or the Task to wor offline. What is the reason that my containers stopes just when updating Quarkus. The Main Branch on 3.2.6.Final is still working fine.

Comment: Can you paste in some of the output from your containers? And some of the output from the Mockito annotations?